# Definition of a reachable ancestor (Skiena TADM 2nd ed section 5.9.2)

Tags: graphs

In *The Algorithm Design Manual* section 5.9.2, covering graphs and articulation vertices, Steven Skiena writes

> Let reachable_ancestor[v] denote the earliest reachable ancestor of vertex v,
>   meaning the oldest ancestor of v that we can reach by a combination of tree edges
>   and back edges.

This phrasing is ambiguous.  On the [errata page](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/algorist/book/errata) of his website, he clarifies:

> it is clearer to say:
>   "denote the earliest reachable ancestor of vertex v, meaning the
>   oldest ancestor of v that we can reach from a descendant of $v$
>   by using a back edge."

But to me, this phrasing is still somewhat ambiguous.  Consider the following four-vertex graph G:

```
    A
    |
+ - B
|   |
|   C
|   |
+ - D
```

We conduct an alphabetical depth-first search (DB is a back edge).  According to Skiena's revised definition, it would seem that A is a reachable ancestor of C as follows:  D is a descendent of C, and we can reach A from D using a back edge by following the path DBA.  However, execution of Skiena's code for finding articulation vertices via depth-first search on G results in reachable_ancestor[C] = B, not A; therefore I don't think he intends for A to count as a reachable ancestor of C.

Might it be more accurate to say that reachable_ancestor is the
oldest ancestor of v that we can reach from a descendant of v
by using a back edge but *without passing through any other ancestors of v*?

Answer (score 1):

A small modification makes the definition agree with Skiena's algorithm. 
"Let reachable_ancestor[v] denote the earliest reachable ancestor of vertex v, meaning the oldest ancestor of v that we can reach from a descendant of v by using *at most one* back edge."

If we view undirected edges as "two-way" directed edges, then to reach A from C would require two back edges: DB and BA.  Thus the earliest ancestor that can be reached from C by using *at most one* back edge is B.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the term *reachable* is used in a rather confusing way. In general conception of graph theorists, *reachable* means that there is a path between two vertices; however, in this context, *reachable* means that there is a back-edge from a vertex in the subtree to one of the ancestors. The existence of such back-edge promises a loop that is free of any articulation vertex.

In my opinion, the use of *reachable* violates the general understanding of connectivity in graph theory. Therefore, Skienna must have revised this in a different way, using the right terminology.

Your reasoning is correct. I suggest you look at the algorithm in "Introduction to Algorithms", which have used "visit_time" instead.